# Monitor Yahoo! Instant Messages in Python?

Tags: python, windows, security, internet-explorer-8, yahoo-messenger

I am trying to add some security to my computer at home and would like to have a copy of all Yahoo! IMs sent to me. I am using Python 2.6 on Windows.

I would also like to have every URL in Internet Explorer sent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark has custom filters for chat protocols like yahoo or to filter for all HTTP traffic.  I don't know why you would want to filter only IE,  its not the most common browser but you could probably filter by user agent.  [Wireshark can be invoked on the commandline](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html) and you can tap into these pre-built filters.  You should use [python's subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to execute Wireshark.